# How to remove dropdown active color in bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on bootstrap 3.0. I have a little problem that I want to remove the active background color of **nav** **dropdown**. See the image below...

[image]

I have tried alot but did not find the bootstrap css which remove this grey color. Can anybody please tell me that how to remove this as I am new to bootstrap. Thanks in advance.

## **Updated**

Please see the code below.

```
<nav class="navbar yamm navbar-default" role="navigation" style="height:0px;">
<div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand glyphicon glyphicon-home" href="#" style="left: 40px;"></a>
</div>

 <div id="navbar-collapse-2" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

<li class="dropdown yamm-fw" style="border-left: 1px dotted #ccc;margin-left: -40px;"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Electronics<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:35%; left:125px; top:30px;">
            <li>
              <div class="yamm-content" style="width:200%;margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="images/electronics/laptops.png"></a>
                  <p class="navbar-txt" style="margin-top: -150px;float: left;">Laptops & Computers</p>
                  <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Explore</button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="images/electronics/projectors.png"></a>                      <p class="navbar-txt" style="margin-top: -140px;float: left;">Tv & Projectors</p>
                  <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Explore</button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="150x190" src="images/electronics/tablets.png"></a>
                  <p class="navbar-txt" style="margin-top: -140px;float: left;">Mobiles & Tablets</p>
                  <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Explore</button>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
 </nav>
```

## **Update 2**# (CSS code)

```
      @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.navbar-brand {
float: left;
height: 83px;
width:125px;
padding: 15px 15px; 
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-left:20px;
}


.glyphicon1 {
position: relative;
left: -5px;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
margin-left: 10px;
}


.dropdown-menu {
left: 250px;
}
.divider1{
height: 1px;
margin: 35px 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #e5e5e5;

}

.dropdown-header1 {
display: block;
padding: 3px 20px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #777;
white-space: nowrap;
margin-top: -25px;

color: #428bca;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.divider2{
height: 1px;
margin: 62px 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
}


.dropdown-header2 {
display: block;
padding: 3px 20px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #777;
white-space: nowrap;
margin-top: -52px;

color: #428bca;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
}



.divider3{
height: 1px;
margin: 35px 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.dropdown-header3 {
display: block;
padding: 3px 20px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #777;
white-space: nowrap;
margin-top: -25px;


color: #428bca;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;

}


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    width:200px;
    font-weight:bold;

}

.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  width:100%;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 285px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 283px;
    z-index: 8;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #999;
  white-space: normal;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu form {
    margin:3px 20px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}


.custom-search-form{
    margin-top:5px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus{
    color: #555;
    background-color: blue; //color change
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/203/

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus{
    color: #555;
    background-color: blue; //color change
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @indubitablee. but I am not using button for drop down. I am doing this in navbar. like (<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    
    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw" style="border-left: 1px dotted #ccc;margin-left: -40px;"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Electronics<b class="caret"></b></a>). can u please modify according to this.

Comment: @UmarWaleed, i edited my answer, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes. But it's not working in my case. can I upload my whole source code so that you modify according to this?? I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: ....you didnt try to implement my solution did you.....literally copy and paste my code into your css file. look at this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/204/

Comment: I tried it but its still not working please see my updated question again for my css code. Please check that what i am doing wrong in my css. thanks alot for your time.

Comment: @UmarWaleed where is your css, you cant do `:active` and :`focus` as inline styles

Comment: i copied everything you posted into a jsfiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/206/

Comment: im saying that there is no problem....not with the code. my code that i wrote is solid, it answers the question, when you put it in your code, it works on jsfiddle, which means its your environment, not the code itself. the only other explanation other than your environment is that you're not referencing the css correctly or that you put your style.css before bootstraps style.css

Comment: thanks alot its working now. I am referencing bootstrap-theme.min.css and when i remove it its work, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

if bootsrap  theme  min included  then you have to add the following css

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus{
    background-image:none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}`